# How to Properly use GoogleMap in PageView in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps

Below is me `Google Map` code in `flutter`:

```
GoogleMap(
          gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
            Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
              () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
            ),
          ].toSet(),
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          markers: _markers,
          initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            _controller = controller;
            isMapCreated = true;
            changeMapMode();
          },
        );
```

this code is inside one of `PageView` Widgets. so the issue is if I keep below code `gestureRecognizers`, I cannot swipe to other pages.

```
gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
            Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
              () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
            ),
          ].toSet(),
```

if I remove it, I can swipe through pages, but then I am not able to use the map properly. what do to ? How to solve this issue ? I know `EagerGestureRecognizer` is the top brass amongs `GestureDectors`. Please guide me through this situation.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is PanGestureRecognizer, which will allow swiping back and forth between your PageView screens (even if you swipe from within the map widget). If you perform a drag across the map widget, then the map widget scrolls. I still find it a little hit & miss though, to drag the map you have to drag up/down a little before it recognizes a left/right drag (assuming your PageView direction is horizontal).

Still, it's much better than EagerGestureRecognizer IMO.

```
gestureRecognizers: {
  Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just can't use both gestures in one page, it will conflict and no good solution and user experience. you can just use PageController for pageview to control the page scrolling with left and right buttons.

And remember to disable scroll in pageview with physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),